# HTTPS negate not working

Tags: url-rewriting, iis-7, iis-8

I have this site "localhost". I want all pages should have https except "localhost/order.aspx?r=15". problem here is it redirect all pages to HTTPS including "localhost/order.aspx?r=15". I have also tried the pattern like 
"^/localhost/order.aspx$"

```html
 <rule name="Force HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" ignoreCase="true" />
    <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="(order.*)" ignoreCase="true" negate="true" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent" />
    </rule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So I fixed it. 
Clear Browser cache, as often time browser remember the HTTPS path. and tries to retrieve the HTTPS even if you provide HTTP only. 
I will recommend using IE to test this.

Update the rule like this.

```html
<rule name="NoSSL - folder" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="order.*" />
   <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
   </conditions>
   <action type="None" />
</rule>
<rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url="(.*)" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
        <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="Found" />
</rule>
```